# Tool to Compare Locust Load Test Results

Tags: python, performance, load-testing, locust, web-api-testing

I'm looking for any recommendations on a tools that can be used to compare load test statistics that Locust outputs.  Currently, after each run, Locust produces either an HTML page in its Web UI or a CSV file. I would like to compare these documents over the course of multiple test runs to see, for example, if a release degrades performance.

I've reviewed the list of [locust extensions](https://github.com/locustio/locust/wiki/Extensions) and found nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You can check out [locust-influx](https://pypi.org/project/locust-influx/) package or [Locust Monitoring with Grafana in Just 15 Minutes](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/locust-grafana) article.

The idea is that Locust will be sending the results to [InfluxDB](https://www.influxdata.com/) and you will be able to come up with a [Grafana](https://grafana.com/) dashboard visualising and comparing different test run results.

Answer (score 0):

I like Dmitri T's answer. I've also considered [JTL Reporter](https://jtlreporter.site/) in the past but never got approval from my company to use it.

The use case is the same as with Grafana like Dmitri suggested, using Locust's [event hooks](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/api.html#event-hooks) to create "listeners" that ship off Locust's stats to a service to store, analyze, and visualize the data to facilitate run comparisons.

https://jtlreporter.site/docs/integrations/locust

Answer (score 0):

Locust Dashboards (a part of `locust-plugins` stores results in Postgres/Timescale, reporting in Grafana) has a useful view for comparing runs over time.

https://github.com/SvenskaSpel/locust-plugins/tree/master/locust_plugins/dashboards